# php concatenate array to array on results of sql query

Tags: php

My Question is , I have array populated from a SQL query and would like to merge the array into a new array where the id of the query is not a duplicate , i have tried merge_array and when i execute the function through the URL it does not display the contents in the array i just get ARRAY.Have also tried to concatenate the array onto another array and get the same result, again my question is how can i join the array and display it correctly.

```
  $rows[0] = array("181", "a","g");  //Results from previous  query
 $rows[1] = array("181","j","L")
 $rows[2] = array("181","p");
 $rows[3] = array("182","k");
 $rows[4] = array("183","l");
 $rows[5] = array("183","p");
 $id =0;
 $commentsH = ""; 

  while( $row=mysql_fetch_array($query_comments) ){

           If($id == $image){  //image id is the first element in array.

           $comments[] =$row;

         $commentsH = $comments.",".$commentsH[$i];

            }

            else{

           $id = $image;
           $i = $i +1;

           }

      }  


  $result = array();
  $result["result"] = 500;
  $result["message"] = "Database Read Successfully";
  $result["comments"] =$commentsH;
  echo json_encode($result);
  exit;


 EXPECTED OUTPUT

 $commentsH[0] = array("181", "a","g","j","L","p");
 $commentsH[1] = array("182","k");
 $commentsH[2] = array("183","l","p");
```

Comment: So ... where is `$image` being declared? You are overwriting `$commentSH` in every iteration and in the code, `$commentsH` is not an array as shown in your _expected output_ .. and the whole line `$commentsH = $comments.",".$commentsH[$i];` doesn't make sense at all ..

Comment: .. and there is something you need to know about using [mysql functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: $image is the result of a query which i haven't included above thought it was obvious , the $commentsH= $comments.",".comments[$i] concatenates both arrays with a ","   between each new array if statement is true , very common in other languages C and Java.

Comment: nonsense, `$commentsH = "" . $commentsH[0]` suggest `$commentsH` is declared as an array elsewhere and being overwritten as as a string. The declaration of `$commentsH = "";` suggest it's a `string`, not an `array`. In C or Java you wouldn't even compile any of it.

Answer (score 0):

This code is wrong

```
while( $row=mysql_fetch_array($query_comments) ){

       If($id == $image){  //image id is the first element in array.

       $comments[] =$row;

     $commentsH = $comments.",".$commentsH[$i];

        }

        else{

       $id = $image;
       $i = $i +1;

       }

  }
```

you are trying to compare with wrong variable, $image will never have the first element of array. Try this

```
while( $row=mysql_fetch_array($query_comments) ){
       $image = $row[0];
       If($id == $image){  //image id is the first element in array.

    // put your further logic here
```

Comment: you are correct that was going to be my next task however i just wanted to get the output correct first then tackle that problem

Answer (score 0):

As briefly mentioned above, you could probably re-work your query to get all the data at once, but, I don't know exactly what this app is supposed to be doing, or the structure of it nor the page, so I'll give an example based on what you're asking.

Keep in mind, the comparing of arrays to merge them should be more dynamic than what I have here, but that can be something for you to add, as I don't know exactly how youre getting your arrays.  Here is only one of many ways to compare and merge:

```
$commentsH = array();
$rows = array();
$rows[0] = array("181", "a","g");  //Results from previous  query
$rows[1] = array("181","j","L", "z", "a");
$rows[2] = array("183", "d", "W", "t");
$rows[3] = array("183", "h", "W", "e");


// check 2 arrays
if(  $rows[0][0] == $rows[1][0]  ){
    for( $j=1; $j<count($rows[1]); $j++ ){
        $found = false;
        $val = "";
        for( $i=1; $i<count($rows[0]); $i++ ){
            if( $rows[1][$j] == $rows[0][$i] ){
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if( $found == false )  array_push( $rows[0], $rows[1][$j] );
    }
}
$commentsH[] = $rows[0];

// check two more ...
if(  $rows[2][0] == $rows[3][0]  ){
    for( $j=1; $j<count($rows[3]); $j++ ){
        $found = false;
        $val = "";
        for( $i=1; $i<count($rows[2]); $i++ ){
            if( $rows[3][$j] == $rows[2][$i] ){
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if( $found == false )  array_push( $rows[2], $rows[3][$j] );
    }
}
$commentsH[] = $rows[2];



// this block simple iterates through the commentsH array and prints out the keys and values cleanly for plain viewing
for( $i=0; $i<count($commentsH); $i++ ){
    foreach( $commentsH[$i] as $key=>$val ){
        echo $key . " => " . $val . "<br />";
    }

    echo "<br /><br />";
}
```

Also, when needing to compare values and merge like that, it can often be easier and more logical to use **associative arrays** as they require unique keys.  You could re-write this to test is an array key already exists with **array_key_exists()**, and if it does, try to merge the arrays with unique values.

Hope this helps ...

Comment: thank you for the response , will give it go and get back to you, thanks